# Nome de usuário

Tags: suporte, usuarios

Então, estava visitando alguns sites da rede, e acabei criando uma conta em mais três sites, são eles: `Stack Overflow, Mathematics e Android Enthusiasts`.

Então eu decidi mudar meu nome de usuário para `array`, no `StackOverflow`, visto que eu já tinha alterado meu nome no `SOpt` uma vez e se tentasse novamente, receberia a mensagem de que só seria possível alterar novamente após 30 dias.

Eu achei que se alterasse meu nome de usuário no `StackOverflow`, este nick só seria visível para usuários do `SO`, ou seja, a alteração só deveria estar disponível lá. Não foi o que aconteceu. O meu nome de usuários das 4 contas foram alterados para o novo.

Quando percebi isso, comecei a explorar um pouco a possível falha e me deparei com isto:

[image: bug1.0]
[image: bug1.0]

> Alterações realizadas
>
> - `Guest` para `array` // Feito no StackOverflow
> - `array` para `guest` // Já era um teste
> - `guest` para `guest0` Outro teste
> - `guest2` para `guest3` // Teste
> - `guest3` para `array` // teste
> - `array` para `array0` // teste final como nos prints

As alterações feitas no SOpt eram concluídas normalmente. Não acredito que seja um privilégio, pois eu poderia mudar o nome a qualquer hora, sem precisar esperar 30 dias.

Então, é realmente um bug ou isto já é `conhecido`?

***Peço desculpas pelas alterações feitas, eu estava apenas testando.***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[EN]

When dealing with different sites, we can't reasonably check if there has been a recent (< 30 days) change of the username on any of the sites you're registered with. We just do it on the site you're currently at.

---

[PT]

> Quando se está lidando com sites diferentes, não podemos,
>   razoavelmente, verificar se houve uma mudança recente (<30 dias) do
>   nome de usuário em qualquer um dos sites que você está registrado. Nós
>   apenas verificamos no site que você está atualmente.

Comentário:

> Eu acho que você acertou em alguns casos extremos, uma vez que o seu
>   usuário foi criado recentemente, e as suas edições foram consecutivas
>   (nós apenas bloqueamos edições depois de se passar algum tempo desde a
>   última edição, no caso de você ter um erro de digitação e
>   precisar corrigir novamente).

Comment: sure. But if I try again on the site that my name has recently changed, The site (I changed 4 times in StackOverflowPT) won't verify anymore if I recently changed my name.

Comment: @array try again today, I think you've hit some edge cases, since your user was only created recently, and your edits were consecutive (we only block edits after some time has passed since the last edit, in case you've made a typo and need to fix again)

Comment: `Display name may only be changed once every 30 days.` haha. @m0sa, thanks for the support, sorry for anything.

Comment: np, glad I could help